# Create JsonObject put not working, nulls

Tags: java, json, string, parsing, object

Im trying to create JsonObcject using code below

```
 try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

            object.put("count", 39);

            JSONArray results = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject resultsAll = new JSONObject();

            resultsAll.put("id", 2);
            resultsAll.put("name", "PlaylistExample");
            resultsAll.put("owned_by", 4);
            resultsAll.put("votes_per_day", 25);
            resultsAll.put("is_subscribed", true);

            results.put(resultsAll);

            object.put("results", results);

            JSONArray finalArray = object.getJSONArray("results");

            JSONObject finalObject = finalArray.getJSONObject(0);

            result = new Results(finalObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But its not working, result is null, same with JsonObject. what am i doing wrong ?

EDIT. Results class with JsonProperties. Thats strange, im trying to create that JsonObcject as a mock for Test

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class Results {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("owned_by")
    private int owned_by;
    @JsonProperty("votes_per_day")
    private int votes_per_day;
    @JsonProperty("tracks_to_play")
    private int tracks_to_play;
    @JsonProperty("is_subscribed")
    private boolean is_subscribed;

    public Results(JSONObject object) {
        try {

            this.id = object.getInt("id");
            this.name = object.getString("name");
            this.owned_by = object.getInt("owned_by");
            this.votes_per_day = object.getInt("votes_per_day");
            this.tracks_to_play = object.getInt("tracks_to_play");
            this.is_subscribed = object.getBoolean("is_subscribed");
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getOwned_by() {
        return owned_by;
    }

    public void setOwned_by(int owned_by) {
        this.owned_by = owned_by;
    }

    public int getVotes_per_day() {
        return votes_per_day;
    }

    public void setVotes_per_day(int votes_per_day) {
        this.votes_per_day = votes_per_day;
    }

    public int getTracks_to_play() {
        return tracks_to_play;
    }

    public void setTracks_to_play(int tracks_to_play) {
        this.tracks_to_play = tracks_to_play;
    }

    public boolean is_subscribed() {
        return is_subscribed;
    }

    public void setIs_subscribed(boolean is_subscribed) {
        this.is_subscribed = is_subscribed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us code for `Results` class? Is it your own class or some library's?

Comment: sure, just a moment

Comment: Also, how do you access `JSONObject object` and get null? In the above code, that seems impossible, since you write `JSONObject object = new JSONObject();` and you never reassign it.

Comment: Iv made breakpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem: I was trying to make that JsonObject within test
without `testCompile 'org.json:json:20140107'` its not possible.